# How to execute HQL commands using .hql files

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hive and wanted to know how to execute hive commoands directly from .hql file.

Comment: `hive -f filename.hql` or `beeline -f filename`

Comment: @philantrovert  thanks. it works

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @rajshukla4696, both `hive -f filename.hql` or `beeline -f filename` will work.

You can also execute queries from the command line via "-e":

`hive -e "select * from my_table"`

There are plenty of useful command line arguments for Hive that can be found here: [Hive Command line Options](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hive/language_manual/cli.html)

Comment: thats for the link. I see we can execute hive commands without going to hive teminal.

Answer (score 1):

Use `hive -f filename.hql;`

Remember to terminate your command with `;`

Answer (score 0):

hive -f filepath;
example-hive -f /home/Nitin/Desktop/Hive/script1.hql;